# Matplotlib legend not showing using mpld3 in Flask app

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, legend, mpld3

I'm building a web app using Flask. Part of that app is plotting some data using matplotlib. I can't seem to get legends to show up at all though. For instance, when I use this example code:

```
data = np.random.randint(0,10,(1000))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data,bins=10,edgecolor='black',label="Entry 1")
ax.legend()
```

This should give a plot with a legend. Now to feed it to my HTML template I first add:

```
output = dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig))
return output
```

Which should turn the plot into a JSON file. I save the JSON file in a dictionary I call 'plot' which I then feed to my HTML template as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mpld3.draw_figure("{{ plot['id'] }}", {{ plot['json']|safe }});
</script>
```

This works as in, a plot is drawn in my app. However it doesn't show a legend:[image]

What is going wrong here?